# how to pull data from different table and display it in different html table on a same page using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have to display data from two different MySql tables in a same page in different HTML tables using PHP, I have two different tables as events and members, I have to pull data from these by their data.

```
<?php
 include_once "dbcon.php"; 
 // Check connection
 if(!$link)
 {
     die('not connected');
 }
 $link=  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE status='1' AND dob BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() ");
 if(!$eventlink)
 {
     die('not connected');
 }

 $eventlink=  mysqli_query($eventlink, "SELECT * FROM events WHERE status='1' AND edate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() ");
?>
```

And in htmli will display the data using while loop, is this correct ?

But it was not working, it always displays "not connected", I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: What is `$link` and what is `$eevntlink` ? Where are they defined ?

Comment: `BETWEEN x AND x+30 AND x` ?????

Comment: <?php

             while($row=  mysqli_fetch_array($link))

             {
                 ?>
                          <td><?php echo $row ['dob']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row ['name']; ?></td>
                          <td><?php echo $row ['bname']; ?></td>
                           <td> <?php ?>

Comment: and the same for event link, i am calling them from each tables head,

Comment: Please provide code where it sets $link and $eventlink variables.

Comment: You can't test if a variable is set before you define it, (well you can but it's pointless in this case), but you can test the returned value when you define it at the same time, so you can go `if ($link = mysqli_query...) { // it set the value so we got true back } else { die('not connected'); }`

Comment: https://pastebin.com/XTaNhFSQ please look into pastebin ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
include_once "dbcon.php"; 
// Check connection
if(!$link)
  {
      die('not connected');
  }
  $link=  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE status='1' AND dob BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() ");

  $eventlink=  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM events WHERE status='1' AND edate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() ");
?>
```

i fixed the issue with the above code, i should have used the $link instead of $eventlink inside the mysqli_query function in the second query, this fixed my issue, thank you guys for trying to help .......

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code, it was added the undefined variable `$eventlink` so that's why it shows you always `not connected`.

```
<?php
include_once "dbcon.php"; 
// Check connection
if(!$link)
  {
      die('not connected');
  }
  $link=  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE status='1' AND dob BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() ");

  $eventlink=  mysqli_query($eventlink, "SELECT * FROM events WHERE status='1' AND edate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() ");
?>
```

Comment: Yes you are correct, but the `$eventlink` variable it not defined any where in file, so it's returning `false`.

Comment: please look in to the pastebin link, i have defined both the variables ,...

Comment: What I am asking issue is solve or not or do I need to update my answer with the complete code?

Comment: Could you please share the complete code on pastebin from top to bottom? I will correct your code and will update my answer.

Comment: you are right, this code was working, but the data from events table are not showed up....

Comment: You have an error in the event sql select statement. Please check the sql query..

Answer (score 0):

Here it looks like the checked variables are set after they are checked.

To help you it would be needed to know how `link` and `eventlink` may look like after line 2. So make it a working example by giving the content of `dbcon.php` (empty/alternative access data) ans also the strukture of your tables (dump with just example data).

Or maybe start with a tutorial, e.g. from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) and learn step by step.

*edit:

the right chapter for you to start is: https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp

there is a function to check the connection:

```
// Check connection
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

The rest was answered by others already.

Also consider to read documentation on the functions you want to use, e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php . There you will find small examples and related functions.

Comment: <?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "password", "myclub");
?>, mydbcon.php content

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine...

```
<?php
        include_once "dbcon.php"; 
        // Check connection

       $link=  mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM members WHERE status='1' AND dob BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() ");
         if(!$link)
               {
                   die('not connected');
               }

        $eventlink=  mysqli_query($eventlink, "SELECT * FROM events WHERE status='1' AND edate BETWEEN CURDATE() AND (CURDATE()+ INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND CURDATE() ");

    if(!$eventlink)
               {
                   die('not connected');
               }

        ?>
```